# Maven dependency not seen from java class

Tags: java, maven

I have switched my Java project to use Maven and it is the first time that I use it.

I have configured my pom.xml file (see below).

Then I do Run As -> Maven Build and I use the Goals "clean install". I can see that all the dependencies are downloaded, which is good but my main class doesn't see them and still says "XXX cannot be resolved to a type". I don't see what I have done wrong.

At the beginning of the file, I had the needed import (ex: "import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;") but Eclipse thinks that this line is not needed and keeps removing it.

Do you know what I have done wrong?
Thanks

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
      <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>8.40.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.dlsc.preferencesfx/preferencesfx-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dlsc.preferencesfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>preferencesfx-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.endrullis.draggabletabs/draggabletabs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.endrullis.draggabletabs</groupId>
      <artifactId>draggabletabs</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.my_company.myproject.MainApp</mainClass>
          <arguments>
          </arguments>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: please post your .classpath file content to diagnose whether it's a configuration problem in the classpath or in the build path

Comment: Have you tried in the context menu of the project "Maven -> Update project"?

Comment: Remove the configuration about sourceDirectory/resources cause they are not needed nor usefulll...follow conventions...keep your classes in `src/main/java` and the tests in `src/test/java`...